# concatenate two integer values into a char array

Tags: c++

Im trying to extract two (int32_t) values, and place them within a char array.

```
int32_t version = getVersion();

if (version < 0)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    //first part of number needs to be shifted right
    int32_t major = (((version) >>16) & 0xFFFF);
    int32_t minor = ((version) & 0xFFFF);

    // need to concatenate these two values, and place a "." between them

    setVersion(...);//requires a char array, should for example be "1.1"
}
```

can anyone give me any advice on the best way to do this? without the use of std::strings please.
I would prefer a char array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show expected input and output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can employ `strstream`

```
char v[255] = {};
{
  std::strstream vs(v, 254);
  vs << major << '.' << minor;
}
setVersion(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it.

```
snprintf(charArray, sizeof(charArray), "%d.%d", major, minor);

// Please check the correctness for format specifier and verify the return 
// value too.
```

If you are on Windows platform, use `_snprintf_s`.

Comment: that looks good, what size would I be required to make the char array? as im extracting these two value, plus the "."?

Comment: As in Johannes answer, you need to have some default size with zero initialized. You can count number of digits in major, minor using some logic and set dynamically size of `charArray` accounting for the size of major+dot+minor+null. But that is up to you as to which way to implement.

Comment: I would consider this good advice for C. But for C++ the danger of incorrect types (and there is no need for speed)  out ways this as a valid usage.